# How to retrieve data using Python and MySQL connector

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I have a MySQL database with a table holding a service (google, reddit, etc) and a password. I want to query the db (SELECT * FROM pwds) and add them to a Python dict, so that the key of the dict is the service, and the value the password. Passwords['google']='G4sR0*KMVC', for example. Here's what I have so far:

```
Passwords = {} #Dictionary to store service and password
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='Bob', password='foobar', host='127.0.0.1', database='passwords')
query = ("SELECT * FROM pwds")
cursor = cnx.cursor(dictionary=True)
cursor.execute(query)
```

When I run this in iPython, after the last step, I can see what's in the cursor
[image]

How can I get what's in the cursor in my dictionary? I've been trying unsuccessfully, and I can't figure it out.

Comment: *I don't want to assume things ahead of time, but if those are your real passwords (which I hope to the Internet Gods they ain't), you should probably change them right away.* Also welcome to SO and the Python side of life. You won't miss .NET a bit!

Comment: Of course not, they are just randomly generated for a password manager I'm making. I'm not showing real passwords online.

Comment: You'd be amazed of the mistakes people make online. They looked like semi complex passwords and usually those are not the norm in examples. So just wanted to be on the safe side and ask. A good question, a friendly reminder is that you have two keys with the same service, bare in mind that these will be replacing one another in a python `dict` since keys are unique (you probably already know this, but again, a reminder)

Comment: Hmm...good point about the password keys. I was thinking more in terms of the DB itself, where both columns are a composite primary key, rather than in terms of the dict itself. I'll make sure that the service uses a different hmac in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
passwords = dict([(row["service"], row["password"]) for row in cursor])
```

Or using a dictionary comprehension (available in Python 2.7+):

```
passwords = {row["service"]: row["password"] for row in cursor}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Passwords = {} #Dictionary to store service and password
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='Bob', password='foobar', host='127.0.0.1', database='passwords')
query = ("SELECT * FROM pwds")
cursor = cnx.cursor(dictionary=True)
cursor.execute(query)

for row in cursor:
    Passwords[row['service']] = row['password']
```

This might be what you're looking for.
Since the rows are actually returned as dict from the `mysql` library, you'll access the individual row "columns" as any other dict.

In short, since a dictionary works by assigning `key` to `value` like so:

```
myDict = {key : val, key : val}
```

With each key being unique, you'll access them with whatever is in the key.

```
myDict = {'name' : 'Torxed', 'type' : 'Funny guy'}
myDict['name']
```

The only difference between `mysql` and the dictionary above is that `mysql` returns a dictionary for each row, but it will be accessed the same way for each individual row.

```
mysqlRows = [ {'name' : 'Torxed', 'type' : 'Funny guy'}, {'name' : 'Amanda', 'type' : 'Has a panda?'} ]
for row in mysqlRows:
    print['name']
```

And what you want, is to take the values from your `mysql` results and store them in your own `key-slot` in your own `dictionary`:

```
Passwords[key] = val
```

Which translates to:

```
Passwords[ row['service'] ] = row['password']
```

Comment: Thank you for the in depth solution! I appreciate the long form answer.

Comment: @Amanda_Panda I hope it was of some use, I mainly leave in depth answers once I got some spare time over for them in case someone stumbles upon your answer later on (Occasional googler dropping by). Best of luck!